# Show HTML tables in django-rest-framework instead raw data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

is it possible to show HTML code like tables with css style instead of json/csv/text/whatever?
I tried to send html as string but it just inserts html like raw text

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just went through this and wanted to share my solution in case anyone else is going through it as well.

What I ended up having to do is shim the `rest_framework.compat.apply_markdown` function to enable the tables extension. At the end of my *settings.py*, I added the following:

```
# Monkey patch rest_framework's markdown rendering function, to enable the
# tables extension.

import markdown
import rest_framework.compat

def apply_markdown(text):
    """
    Simple wrapper around :func:`markdown.markdown` to set the base level
    of '#' style headers to <h2>.
    """
    extensions = ['markdown.extensions.toc', 'markdown.extensions.tables']
    extension_configs = {
        'markdown.extensions.toc': {
            'baselevel': '2'
        }
    }
    md = markdown.Markdown(
        extensions=extensions, extension_configs=extension_configs
    )
    return md.convert(text)

rest_framework.compat.apply_markdown = apply_markdown
```

In this case I'm using DRF 3.6.4 and markdown 2.6.9. In the original `rest_framework.compat.apply_markdown` function there's some code that sets different options based on the version of markdown, but I omitted that in the shim.

Also note that the default tables extension may not give you tables styled the way you want. I ended up copying *markdown/extensions/tables.py* into a new module and adding `class="table"` to the `table` element. The source for that change is [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/mjumbewu/df81a591c6a1a6176a372791691269d2). For more information about the limited table syntax in markdown see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830882/python-markdown-add-class-to-table).

Answer (score 0):

For `djangorestframework>=3.7` update the default view description function.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#view_description_function

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Module path to a callable which should have a signature (self, html=False)
    'VIEW_DESCRIPTION_FUNCTION': 'app_name.view_description.get_view_description',
}
```

`view_description.py`

```
import markdown
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from rest_framework.compat import (
    HEADERID_EXT_PATH, LEVEL_PARAM, md_filter_add_syntax_highlight
)
from rest_framework.utils import formatting


TABLE_EXTENSION_PATH = 'markdown.extensions.tables'

def _apply_markdown(text):
    extensions = [HEADERID_EXT_PATH, TABLE_EXTENSION_PATH]
    extension_configs = {
        HEADERID_EXT_PATH: {
            LEVEL_PARAM: '2'
        }
    }
    md = markdown.Markdown(
        extensions=extensions, extension_configs=extension_configs
    )
    md_filter_add_syntax_highlight(md)
    return md.convert(text)


def get_view_description(view_cls, html=False):
    description = view_cls.__doc__ or ''
    description = formatting.dedent(smart_text(description))

    if html:
        return mark_safe(_apply_markdown(description))
    return description
```

Answer (score 0):

in your settings.py use renderer classes.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.AdminRenderer',
    ],
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed the markdown and django-filter packages? These were required to get our HTML browsing capability working on a recent project.

```
sudo pip install markdown
sudo pip install django-filter
```

Comment: I installed both markdown and django-filter.
 Only raw json extraction of comments show up. and show/hide, list operations, expand operation show nothing on cliicking them.

Comment: doesn't resolve my issue with these two are already installed.