# pandoc add class to table in markdown

Tags: html, css, markdown, pandoc

For a heading, for a code-block, for a span element we can with pandoc add `{.class}` to add a class.

```
# Heading 1 {.my_class_for_heading1}

Here is some `code`{.my_class_for_code} and 
for a [span]{.my_class_for_span} it is working as well
and for img and url it is available as well
for [pandoc](http://www.pandoc.org/){.my_class_for_url}
```

I'm working with bootstrap, and it would be nice to specify "table" and/or "table-hover" as class such that the html view gets the table decorated with bootstrap CSS.

Anyone?

Comment: This may be related: [Python markdown add class to table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21830882/866026). While that discusses a different tool (so not strictly a duplicate), the same syntax is supported and I expect the same reasoning would apply. I also suspect the way to work around it will be the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In pandoc's internal document AST, tables have attributes since pandoc 2.10, but the [markdown reader hasn't been updated for that yet](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6317). (Same for [other formats](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen++new+table+features+).)

However, you can:

- wrap a table in a raw HTML div with a class (this won't work for bootstrap CSS which expects the class to be on the table),
- write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html), or
- probably in this case easier: post-process the output HTML to add a class.

Comment: option #3 is what I did, using jquery.

Comment: myself I prefer perl at the commandline for modifying the resulting html in place. Something like: 

`perl -pi -e 's/<table>/<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">/' output.html`

for working with bootstrap table classes.

Comment: Think this can help to solve it using a Paru filter: https://github.com/htdebeer/paru/blob/master/examples/filters/add_css_class_to_tables.rb